# /v3/SoftLayer_Account/getObject.json REST endpoint is returning an empty response for me

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

This REST call returns 200 OK but an empty response against a certain master account:

```
curl -XGET -u UNAME:PASS https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getObject.json?objectMask=filteredMask%5Binvoices%5Bid%2CcreateDate%2CtypeCode%5D%5D
```

Other master accounts return json data.  I don't feel comfortable posting the username for that master here, but according to SoftLayer support Stack Overflow is the place to reach a developer who can look into it. I'm dubious about that obviously but if it really is so, the ticket # is 29250537.

I'll now brace myself for moderation.

**Update 1**

Result limit set to offset=0, limit=1 works on other accounts but not this one:

```
$ curl -vvv -u ... 'https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getObject.json?objectMask=filteredMask%5Binvoices%5Bid%2CcreateDate%2CtypeCode%5D%5D&resultLimit=0,1'
*   Trying 66.228.119.120...
* Connected to api.softlayer.com (66.228.119.120) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
* Server certificate: api.softlayer.com
* Server certificate: RapidSSL SHA256 CA - G3
* Server certificate: GeoTrust Global CA
* Server auth using Basic with user '...'
> GET /rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getObject.json?objectMask=filteredMask%5Binvoices%5Bid%2CcreateDate%2CtypeCode%5D%5D&resultLimit=0,1 HTTP/1.1
> Host: api.softlayer.com
> Authorization: Basic ...
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
>
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 200 OK
< Date: Mon, 06 Jun 2016 14:35:51 GMT
< Server: Apache
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Connection: close
<
* Closing connection 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is due to your account has a huge amount of invoices (roughly 31000), this error is expected when you try to fetch such huge amount of data. In order to avoid this error you have to filter your data using objectFilter or result limmits.

I suggest you to use resultlimits try this request:

```
GET https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getInvoices.json?objectMask=filteredMask[id,createDate,typeCode]&resultLimit=0,5000
```

http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-filters
https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/REST

try this curl

```
$ curl -XGET -u user:api "https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getInvoices.json?objectMask=filteredMask%5Bid%2CcreateDate%2CtypeCode%5D&resultLimit=0%2C5000"
```

and notice that I am using the getInvoices method, if you try to use the getObjec method the resultlimmits will not work

Regards

Comment: Thanks for the reply- unfortunately the resultlimit is not helping with this account and the error is still hidden.

Comment: It is working I tested with your account, the problem could be the REST client you are using is not applying the result limmit, try using Postman or Insomnia for Chrome browser or curl

Comment: Neglected to say- please see the update for details.

Comment: I added a curl example try that

Comment: OK your curl command on getInvoices works for me and mine on getObject doesn't.  My bad- one result is everything in the world after the join nests the invoices.  Thanks.